# How should I destroy a Mob Spawner?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just came across my first dungeon in Minecraft, and already the Mob Spawner is giving me problems. What would be a quick way to destroy the Spawner? All the Minecraft wiki mentioned was ways to trap mobs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To break one, use a pickaxe, preferably Iron level or higher.  Note, once you destroy one, it will not drop as a block, so break these only if you'd like to get rid of them permanently.

While your opinion may differ, I find spawners to be excellent exp farms, and you can turn yours into a mob farm.

If you'd rather save your Mob Spawner, you need to block it off with light, similar to placing torches in a cave to ward off mob spawns. To de-activate a mob spawner, place torches around the spawner (at least an 8 block radius) to prevent mobs from spawning.  Put them adjacent to the block itself.

Comment: Unless it is really in the middle of your building plans, you might want to keep it though, just in case you'd later on decide you like the whole mob trap idea.

Comment: Protip: If it's a skeleton spawner, just break a one block hole out of the wall, let them see you, and back away. The skeletons will start shooting and hit each other on accident. The ones caught in the crossfire will turn on their allies and kill each other off.

Comment: @Sonic42  Kinda late, but if you do that method, then you won't get any exp orbs out of it.  Not worth my time.

Comment: @JimmyChen That's true, I never thought about that because I haven't used that method since XP was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

I always surround them in cobblestone, just in case I want to harvest later.

Pop torches all round to dissuade spawning, then build walls, ceiling and a floor.

When you want to harvest, build your grinder below and then knock out the floor and remove the torches.

And then run away :-)

Comment: Do remember, though, that their spawn radius is often larger than the room they're in. I get mobs spawning in the hallway outside the spawn room often.

Comment: You can easily check the radius by looking at the moss covered blocks (for a mature spawner anyway). As long as they are covered you should be fine.

Comment: Mob spawners spawn inside an 8x8x3 square around them. Dungeons are often 5x5 or 5x7, in which case the area around the dungeon (often a cave) can be partially inside the radius of the spawner despite lacking moss stone. Furthermore, Cave Spider Spawners spawn in friggan hallways rather than rooms at all, with no moss stone.

Comment: oooh - didn't know that, and never seen it, so thanks for letting me know!

Comment: The moss stone is created when the world is generated; it doesn't "grow" and it gives no indication of the size of the spawner's radius. It's just part of the randomly-determined size of the dungeon room.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to destroy a mob spawner quickly, you want to place torches close to the spawner and destroy it after killing the remaining mobs around you to stop them from slowing you down. This method differs between different spawners. Cave spider spawners are difficult to get rid of for a begginer. You should destroy the webs from a distance  and place torches frequently to prevent the spawn rate and eventually stop them spawning. Cane spiders spawn quite quickly and do give decent xp. This may encourage you to make a mod trap.

Answer (score -1):

A quick and easy solution is to blow it up.

I once tried building a mob farm in a mine when a few creepers ambushed me and blew me to kingdom come along with the spawner. [ :( ]